# Is there a way to fit a given time frame of a a video to fit a specific file size?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split, video-encoding, video-conversion

Is there a ffmpeg command to fit part of a video into a certain file size? For example, if it is a 645mb video that is 70 minutes long, and I want 7 parts (each part 10 mins)- to limit each part to 93 mb (the average estimated file size)?

(*I already tried to break it up by timestamp,but the files don't end up the same size*)

Comment: If you're not re-encoding, this can't be guaranteed --> 10 mins, 93 MB.

Comment: @Gyan True but it will only vary slightly.

Comment: Don't know of a way to limit it by size, dividing original file size by parts and then varying the amount of parts will give a rough indicator of each part size if split equally.